# How to keep button position locked when it is inside a table (mobile webpage)

Tags: html, css, formatting, jsfiddle

The position of my "Download" button in the following code depends on the size of the text to the left of it. If the text is long the button gets pushed to the right and if the text is small the button is too far to the left.

```
<td><p><strong>jk</strong></p><div><p>jk</p></div><span class="rating stars-4"></span></td>
<td><p><strong>Version:2.0</strong></p><a class="button-flat" href = "http://randomdomfile.com/random.txt>Download</a></td>
```

I have also attached a picture to show what I mean. 
[image]

Basically, the position of the Version and Download is depending on the size of the title or "jk". I want the button and version to be pushed to the right edge of the screen at all times. How would I do this?

UPDATE: Here's the new code I am using according to what you said:

```
<td><p><strong>jk</strong></p><div><p>jk</p></div><span class="rating stars-4"></span></td>
<td><div class = "newformat"><p><strong>Version:2.0</strong></p><a class="button-flat" href = "http://randomdomfile.com/random.txt>Download</a></div></td>

.newformat{
     position:absolute; 
     right:0;
}



a.button-flat {
display: block;
line-height: 40px;
height: 40px;
width: 100px;
background: #F6F6F6 url(../images/sprite-button-flat.png) repeat-x 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #D8D8D8;
border-left: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
border-right: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
border-top: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333333;
padding: 0 .3em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Include a JSFiddle for greater help ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *position:absolute* and *right:0* on button's CSS.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Also, this only moves the button to the right. I tried to add the same thing for the version text but it disappears if I do that. How would I push the version to the right also?

Comment: Include version and download in a single element (say div) and push this div to right.

Edit: If that doesn't work, please provide me the related markup.

Comment: ok I tried that and it made the button background disappear and the button itself disappear also, but the text on the button remained. Also, the title and description appeared on either side of "Download" now. I will update the question with the new code and markup.

Comment: Okay. Revert back to your previous code. And use text-align:right for parent <td> of Version text. Use inline CSS on that <td>. I could be of more help if that site is hosted anywhere. It would be nice if you host it on some free hosting server like 000webhost and give me the link if you want quick efficient resolution.

Comment: Ok, that worked for the version and button. But now the ratings is cut off and the title+description ("jk") is not staying to the left along with the image. It's ok if you can't help me with that. thanks for fixing the button+version.

Comment: It actually is already hosted there, I will private message you the link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32424/discussion-between-user2463517-and-abhijit)

Comment: I invited you to a private chat.